when I upgrade MAUI to version 9, I get this error message : The type or namespace name 'MauiWinUIApplication' could not be found
I have built a demo projet just to display a bitmap with Skiasharp.
Nothing special :
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    SKBitmap mybitmap;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Assembly assembly = GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
        using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MauiApp3.Resources.Images.dotnet_bot.png"))
        {
            mybitmap = SKBitmap.Decode(stream);
        }

    }

    void OnCanvasViewPaintSurface(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs args)
    {
        SKImageInfo info = args.Info;
        SKSurface surface = args.Surface;
        SKCanvas canvas = surface.Canvas;

        canvas.Clear(SKColors.Black);

        // Get the bitmap and center it
        SKBitmap bitmap = mybitmap;
        canvas.DrawBitmap(bitmap, info.Rect, null);
    }
}

And in the xaml file :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:skia="clr-namespace:SkiaSharp.Views.Maui.Controls;assembly=SkiaSharp.Views.Maui.Controls"
            Title="Animated Gif"
            x:Class="MauiApp3.MainPage">

    <Grid RowDefinitions="*,Auto">
        <skia:SKCanvasView x:Name="canvasView" 
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        PaintSurface="OnCanvasViewPaintSurface" />
        <Label Text="GIF file by DemonDeLuxe from Wikipedia Newton's Cradle page"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Margin="0,5"
            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>

</ContentPage>

this work fine with this version of the nuget :

But when I upgrade MAUI to version 9, I get this error message :

The type or namespace name 'MauiWinUIApplication' could not be found
(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

on this line of the App.xaml.cs file in the platform/windows folder :
public partial class App : MauiWinUIApplication

Any idea to solve this ? Skiasharp is not compatible with maui 9 ?

This question is similar to: The type or namespace name 'MauiWinUIApplication' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Maui'. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You have installed .NET 9 sdk?
